# Not able to show the right list in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, list, select, left-join

i have been messing around with MySQL queries for a few days and i cant seem to get a solution.

i'm making a kind of achievement list. what i want is to make SELECT query where the user can see all his achievements.

i have my database like this:

```
Badges 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| idbadges (PK) | subject_subject (FK) | description   | pathToImage |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1             | (subject)            | (description) | (image)     |
| 2             | (subject)            | (description) | (image)     |
| 3             | (subject)            | (description) | (image)     |
| 4             | (subject)            | (description) | (image)     |
| 5             | (subject)            | (description) | (image)     |
| 6             | (subject)            | (description) | (image)     |
| 7             | (subject)            | (description) | (image)     |
| 8             | (subject)            | (description) | (image)     |
| 9             | (subject)            | (description) | (image)     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------

ScoreList - Many to Many relationship
--------------------------------------------------------
| users_email(FK/PK) | badges_idbadges (FK/PK) | done  | 
--------------------------------------------------------
| 1111@test.com      | 1                       | 2     | 
| 1111@test.com      | 2                       | 1     | 
| 1111@test.com      | 3                       | 0     | 
| 1111@test.com      | 4                       | 0     | 
| 2222@test.com      | 1                       | 0     | 
| 2222@test.com      | 2                       | 1     | 
| 2222@test.com      | 6                       | 2     | 
| 2222@test.com      | 7                       | 3     | 
--------------------------------------------------------
```

every user has a list of badges. those badges have a Done value, a 0 means not gotten the badges and everything above means the amount you got. if the badges isnt in the scoreList for that user then it defaults in a 0 (inside the program. not in the database).

what i want is to show a list what the user has. if the user doesnt have a certain badge (or the data is not there) i want to have a NULL value in its place

example:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|users_email  |idbadges|subject_subject|description  |pathToImage|done|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|1111@test.com|1       |(subject)      |(description)|(image)    |2   |
|1111@test.com|2       |(subject)      |(description)|(image)    |1   |
|1111@test.com|3       |(subject)      |(description)|(image)    |0   |
|1111@test.com|4       |(subject)      |(description)|(image)    |0   |
|NULL         |5       |(subject)      |(description)|(image)    |NULL|
|NULL         |6       |(subject)      |(description)|(image)    |NULL|
|NULL         |7       |(subject)      |(description)|(image)    |NULL|
|NULL         |8       |(subject)      |(description)|(image)    |NULL|
|NULL         |9       |(subject)      |(description)|(image)    |NULL|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

i feel like this should be an easy thing to do with a LEFT JOIN but i cant seem to get it. what i have right now is:

```
SELECT 
    IF (s.users_email = '1111@test.com', s.users_email,null) AS users_email,
    b.*,
    IF (s.users_email = '1111@test.com', s.done,null) AS done
FROM
badges b
    LEFT JOIN
scoreList s ON b.idbadges = s.badges_idbadges
```

and this almost works but the result i get is:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|users_email  |idbadges|subject_subject|description  |pathToImage|done|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|NULL         |1       |(subject)      |(description)|(image)    |NULL|
|1111@test.com|1       |(subject)      |(description)|(image)    |2   |
|NULL         |2       |(subject)      |(description)|(image)    |NULL|
|1111@test.com|2       |(subject)      |(description)|(image)    |1   |
|1111@test.com|3       |(subject)      |(description)|(image)    |0   |
|1111@test.com|4       |(subject)      |(description)|(image)    |0   |
|NULL         |5       |(subject)      |(description)|(image)    |NULL|
|NULL         |6       |(subject)      |(description)|(image)    |NULL|
|NULL         |7       |(subject)      |(description)|(image)    |NULL|
|NULL         |8       |(subject)      |(description)|(image)    |NULL|
|NULL         |9       |(subject)      |(description)|(image)    |NULL|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

thats because it still reads the results of the other users (2222@test.com)
does anyone know how to get the result as in example one? if you need any other information im happy to provide as long as its not personal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really close, you're just over complicating it a little.  Instead of those `IF` statements, add a filter to the user you want to see on your join.  You'll also want an `ORDER BY` to guarantee your results come back as expected:

```
SELECT s.users_email,
       b.*,
       s.done
FROM badges b
LEFT JOIN scoreList s ON b.idbadges = s.badges_idbadges
                      AND s.users_email = '1111@test.com'
ORDER BY b.idbadges
```

Comment: thank you very much!! i really hate when the answers are so simple after i looked at for so long

Comment: @RonPelt NP, and I'm sure you at least learned more by trying to solve it yourself first.  Happy coding :D

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT [columns you want] 
from badges 
left join ScoreList on badges.idbadges = ScoreList.badges_idbadges AND 
ScoreList.users_email = '1111@test.com'
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer if you are happy with it. Thanks